# Unable to download NSE Bhavcopy zip file in R. HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Tags: html, r

I am trying to download zip file in R (basically I am automating). On the below webpage I can download the zip if I click on the zip file.

I can even download if I do right click and save the file. However, I am not able to download it via R. So far I have tried `download.file`, `RCurl` and `downloader` packages. But no success yet!

```
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2009/JAN/fo07JAN2009bhav.csv.zip"
download.file(url, dest);

> trying URL
> 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2009/JAN/fo07JAN2009bhav.csv.zip'
> Error in download.file(url, temp) :    cannot open URL
> 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2009/JAN/fo07JAN2009bhav.csv.zip'
> In addition: Warning message: In download.file(url, temp) :   cannot
> open URL
> 'https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2009/JAN/fo07JAN2009bhav.csv.zip':
> HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Manual Download:

- Open:
  https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/archieve_fo.htm
- Select: bhavcopy from drop down
- Select date: 07-01-2009 (I need data from 2010-2015)
- click on zip file OR right click on zip and do save as.

Comment: I get: `Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/DERIVATIVES/2009/JAN/fo07JAN2009bhav.csv.zip" on this server.
Reference #18.d532c517.1520963769.2b3a31e3` so it looks like your "manual download" was dependent on setting in your browser that are not being replicated by the console session. Furthermore the TOS includes this: `You may not conduct any systematic or automated data collection activities (including scraping, data mining, data extraction and data harvesting) on or in relation to our website without our express written consent.`

Comment: The web page runs JavaScript to obtain the data from the secure archive. You could use the RSelenium package to permit R to interact with the web page (enter strings, etc.) and achieve the same results as using your mouse and keyboard. Might be worth exploring if you have many of these to do.

Answer (score 0):

`download.file` doesn't work for NSE Bhavcopy before 2016. Hence use `RSlenium`.

Refer package `nser` https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/nser/index.html to download the FO Bhavcopy.

```
library(nser)
library(RSelenium)

# Start a selenium server and browser
# For Google Chrome (Update Chrome to latest version)

 driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"), port = 3163L, chromever = "91.0.4472.101")
 remDr <- driver$client

# or for Firefox
 driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"), port = 3799L)
 
# Download Equity Bhavcopy zip file
bhavfos("03012000", 2)

# Close the Browser
remDr$close()
```